# Javascript- Array functions :Create a function that accepts a single parameter as an argument: an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

total newbie here but I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now. Here is the Javascript problem:

Write a function getMultipleLengthsthat accepts a single parameter as an argument: an array of strings. The function should return an array of numbers where each number is the length of the corresponding string.

this is what it should console log:

```
console.log(getMultipleLengths(["hello", "what", "is", "up", "dude"]));
// [5,4,2,2,4]
```

Here is my code:

```
function getMultipleLengths(arr){
  arr.forEach(function(str){
    return str.length;
  })
return arr
}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a homework or job interview question, so I will not spell out the answer for you.  But you're pretty close to a solution.  `return` from each iteration of a  `forEach` doesn't modify the input array, but there are other array methods that do....   alternatively, consider using a separate array to store your lengths and returning that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function `forEach()` is the wrong function here. You may want to use the function `map()`:

```
function getMultipleLengths(arr){
    return arr.map(function(str){
        return str.length;
    });
}
```

This function can be used to return a specific value for each array element and returns you a complete new array with the "new" values (in this case the lengths).

You can find more information about `map()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
function getMultipleLengths(arr){
let resultArray=[];
  arr.forEach(function(str){
    resultArray.push( str.length);
  });
console.log(resultArray);
return resultArray;
}
```